# File or directory 'shelves' is out of date; try updating - BitBucket Server Svn Mirror

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bitbucket, subgit

Getting error

> File or directory 'shelves' is out of date; try updating

With BitBucket Server Svn Mirror when merging branch from `git` command line, or web interface. (This question differs from others about the same issue, as it's not related to TortoiseSVN or local SVN repository access).

[image]

Comment: Is the SVN Mirror add-on version 3.2.0? If yes, consider upgrading to the newest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an TortoiseSVN on windows.

The solution for me is to svn update the directory, even though there are no revisions to download or update. It does something to the metadata, which magically fixes it.

Comment: "Its an TortoiseSVN on windows." - can you please explain, how does it relate to Bitbucket Server(ex Atlassian Stash)?